# Is it ok to put large no. of images in drawable

Tags: android, android-image

I am new to android

In my app I am using around 600 images. There are jpeg of average size of 4.0KB, total would be auround 2.4MB. I have all these images in res/drawable/. Is it OK to have so many images in drawable ? or should I move them in SD card. I also considered to store them in sqlLite but I see that its not a recommended. Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: If the images will be high quality in the future or updated, it might be useful to download/cache segments of images as needed. This way you only use the images you need and can update the images without updating the app.

Answer (score 0):

2.4MB isn't much, so you should be fine. However, if you expect this to go up, or require 2.4MB for each drawable folder, you should consider downloading them to the SD Card when required.

Internal storage on devices is limited mostly, and users uninstall apps that take too much space quite often.

You could also set `installLocation` in the manifest to `auto` to allow your app to be moved to the SD Card

Answer (score -2):

It is absolutly fine, google creates several versions of apk for different resoulutions, so users will not suffer for extra space caused by extra drawable folders. Exeption: if you have really a lot of resourses ( e.g resourse folder will be 32+M ) you have to add android:largeHeap="true" to your manifest.

Comment: Google does not "creates several versions of apk for different resolutions". They are put into different drawable folder, which is different. Additionally, you are confusing disk memory taken by APK and its resource with RAM. Just because you have large resource folder doesn't mean that android:largeHeap should/needs to be set.